# How do I close a SearchView programmatically?

Tags: android, searchview

I currently have a `SearchView` in the action bar of my app. When I click the search icon, the `SearchView` expands and the keyboard pops up as expected. Clicking the "X" in the `SearchView` box closes the `SearchView` as expected. However, when the `SearchView` is activated and I press the "back" button, my app is exited. This is the correct behavior, but what I am trying to do now is to capture back button press and just have it close the `SearchView` (not my app) when the `SearchView` is visible. Is there a way to invoke the `SearchView` `OnCloseListener()` programmatically on a back button press? For example, something like this:

```
// On a back button press, if we are currently searching,
// close the SearchView. Otherwise, invoke normal back button
// behavior.
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (isSearchViewVisible) {
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchBox)
               .getActionView();

            // This method does not exist
            searchView.invokeClose();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46930606/1308990

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Based on @MarcinOrlowski answer, also you can use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Important, the above solution won't work if the you have set
app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: Make sure to set searchView.setQuery("", false); in order to make searchView.setIconified(true); to work

Comment: using searchView.setQuery("", false); before searchView.setIconified(true); worked for me, also if you put 2 successive  searchView.setIconified(true);   worked for me.

Answer (score 59):

Use

```
searchView.setIconified(true)
```

I also used [MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html#collapseActionView(android.view.MenuItem))

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(menuItem)
```

**EDITED**

> This method was deprecated in API level 26.1.0. Use collapseActionView() directly.

[MenuItem#collapseActionView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#collapseActionView())

Comment: This only works if you set app:showAsAction="ifroom|collapseActionView".

Comment: Now is deprecated, Use collapseActionView() on the MenuItem directly

Answer (score 52):

There is a simple way to do this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
        searchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

or use:

```
myToolBar.collapseActionView();
```

This will make the searchView to collapse before you press the back then the back action will be called.

Both solutions will work.

Comment: collapseActionView not works, the first solution yes

Comment: Only your method worked.

Answer (score 38):

this is the only thing that does it for me:

```
  toolbar.collapseActionView();
```

Comment: I tried all solution in this thread. this solution is the best for me. it is the only solution that made search icon back to top-right screen

Comment: IDE gives me "Actionbar.collapseActionView can only be called from within the same library group"  error

Comment: `supportActionBar?.collapseActionView()` worked for me

Answer (score 23):

To intercept BACK button override `onBackPressed()` ([see docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29))

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (isSearchViewVisible) {
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchBox)
           .getActionView();

        // This method does not exist
        searchView.invokeClose();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

[Docs say](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

> If necessary, you can expand or collapse the action view in your own
>   code by calling expandActionView() and collapseActionView() on the
>   MenuItem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! What I'm mainly interested in though is whether there is a way to programmatically invoke a SearchView's close event i.e. Imitate an SearchView box "X" button press in code.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Marcin. It turns out what I actually wanted to do was the "iconify" my search actionview (my searchview is always on the action bar and never collapses into the options menu). Thanks for taking the time to help me and thanks for the tip on overriding "onBackPressed."

Comment: For me onBackPressed is not called. what other solution do I have ? I tried to listen for the focus on the searchview but that isn't called also..

Comment: You do not expect `onBackPressed()` outside of Activity (i.e. in Fragment), do you?

Comment: For me, onBackPressed not being called at all.  It seems the search view is actually eating up the back press and handling it.  For example, I see that onMenuItemActionViewCollapsed() is called, but onBackPressed is not called.  How can I override this?  I even tried setting a Key Listener on the search view and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think this won't work if search view is in actionbar. It is always visible. So we it won't go to the else part.  setIconified() works for me

Comment: @AshokSoThree I've the same issue you described! I've the `Done` button, I don't know how to handle this button if the user searched with empty text! I want to hide the search view if the user click on `Done` button with empty text...do you've any ideas? Please share if you've any. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that for `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` the methods are `onActionViewCollapsed()` and `onActionViewExpanded()`.

Comment: Where does menu come from?

Answer (score 21):

if you have input on your searchView

```
mSearchView.setIconified(true);
```

will only clear the text.

The correct method to close a searchView is

```
mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
```

Answer (score 4):

No need to use `onBackPressed()` method for this!! 
I found the solution, do only as I mentioned below so that the SearchView itself handle the **on back button press** event.

Inside your `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method,

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchview = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchview.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchview.setQueryHint("Enter your keyword");
    searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(this); 
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

In your **menu.xml** add *showAsAction* attribute and set its values as `"always|collapseActionView"`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search_item"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_logo"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

And you're ready to go ;)

**P.S. - I was searching for a solution from a long time and now I found one, hope it helps you all.**

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `!searchView.isIconified()` over `if(isSearchViewVisible)` inside the `onBackPressed()` method as option 2 does not work when you have fragments added in your `fragmentmanager's` `backstack` that you would like to show when the back button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin;

Firstly clear the typed text (optional)

```
searchView.isIconified = true
```

Second, close the searchview

```
searchView.onActionViewCollapsed()
```

Exstra, open searchview programatically

```
searchView.onActionViewExpanded()
```

Answer (score 0):

My way:

1. Create CustomSearchView class

```
    public class CustomSearchView extends SearchView{
        public CustomSearchView(final Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && 
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                this.onActionViewCollapsed();
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
        }
    }
```

2. Add actionViewClass

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        android:actionViewClass="com.myapp.CustomSearchView"/>
```

3. Create CustomSearchView into onCreateOptionsMenu

```
    CustomSearchView searchView = (CustomSearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not use any function in `onBackPressed()` method ,remove it from your Activity.So that the  `SearchView` itself handle the `onBackPress` event.

I am using SearchView as

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchview = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchview.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchview.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);  
    searchview.setQueryHint("Search Here"); 
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

and  my menu.xml as follows

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search_tool"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="Search" 
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `collapseActionView`. It automatically handle back button, collapsing SearchView

```
<item
      android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_magnify"
      android:title="@string/action_title_search"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. I am trying to close search-view from Fragment in Jetpack NavigationView when a user clicks the back button -

requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
@Override
public void handleOnBackPressed() {

```
        try {
            DashboardActivity activity = (DashboardActivity) getActivity();
            if (activity!=null) {
                if (!activity.mSearchView.isIconified()) {
                    activity.mSearchView.setQuery("",false);
                    activity.mSearchView.setIconified(true);
                } else {
                    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
                    navController.popBackStack();
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Most Worked Solution:**

```
MenuItem menuItem = ....//
menuItem.collapseActionView();
```